# What Year Was Lore Born And When Did He Die?

Tags: star-trek

I was reading the article [Lore](https://memory-beta.fandom.com/wiki/Lore) in the Memory Beta, non-canon Star Trek Wiki, and it says Lore was born 2335 to 2364.
But this [Memory Alpha page on Lore](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Lore) says he died 2370.

Which is right?

Comment: I'm not familiar with either site, but Memory Beta has "non-canon" written across the header in big bold letters, so I'm gonna say it's not that one...?

Comment: Lore is a robot, not a biological organism, so he never was born or died.  He was just activated and deactivated several times.

Comment: this was a duplicate comment

Answer (score 4):

### 2335/6 - 2371

Lore was brought online between 2335 and 2336 and was finally deactivated in 2370 (at the end of [TNG: Descent, Part II](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Descent,_Part_II_(episode))). Both dates are confirmed in the [Star Trek Encyclopedia](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Star_Trek_Encyclopedia).

> ***Lore was activated around 2335 or 2336***, but was shut down by Soong
>   shortly afterward because the colonists at Omicron Theta viewed Lore
>   as a threat.

and

> Starbase 295: The Enterprise-D headed to Starbase 295 **after
>   encountering the self-aware Borg in 2370.** ("Decent, Part II" [TNG])

He was finally *destroyed* (irreparably) in 2371 [when the Enterprise crash-landed on Veridian III at the end of Star Trek: Generations](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/79126/20774)

Comment: Wasn't the Enterprise-D part of Generations in 2371?

Comment: @Daishozen - Oops.

Comment: How much time is "shortly afterward"?   I.e. how long was he online the first time?

Comment: @ThePopMachine - The crystalline entity attacked the colony in 2338. That gives us a three year window during which time he was apparently awake. He could have been online for a day, a week or all three years but we know it was sufficient time for him to piss off the colonists, for Soong to shut him off (and pack him away) and make a more amenable version.

Comment: @Valorum:   Well, the reason I ask, is that if he was online for, say, only a year, that is pretty remarkable that he developed quickly enough to get to the level he was when we first meet him.   Or otherwise, Soong did such a good job designing him, that he basically didn't need a childhood like Lal and B-4, and presumably Data, to some extent did.

Comment: @ThePopMachine - Soong was experimenting with mind transfers which is why Data has a bunch of memories from the colonists. Presumably if he dialled that up to 11, the robot would be a gestalt of all of the mind scans. Which is probably why he was able to develop so fast and why he turned evil, now that I think about it.